# C++ - HMAC MD5 is not equals with online generator

Tags: c++, openssl, md5, hmac

In my code, I want to generate HMAC MD5. so:

```
void Gen()
{
    CString newKey = L"320E6FADB2738DA273A41E14F85027E1";
    unsigned char bNewKey[16];
    memset(bNewKey, 0, 16);
    string k = ws2s(newKey.GetString());
    hex_to_bytes(k.c_str(), bNewKey, 16);

    CString data = L"35413B1DD9AB9FA0F1395759BD72451C";
    string d = ws2s(data.GetString());
    unsigned char bData[16];
    memset(bData, 0, 16);
    hex_to_bytes(d.c_str(), bData, 16);
    

    //unsigned char bNewKey[16] = { 0x32,0x0E,0x6F,0xAD,0xB2,0x73,0x8D,0xA2,0x73,0xA4,0x1E,0x14,0xF8,0x50,0x27,0xE1 };
    //unsigned char bData[16] = { 0x35,0x41,0x3B,0x1D,0xD9,0xAB,0x9F,0xA0,0xF1,0x39,0x57,0x59,0xBD,0x72,0x45,0x1C };

    unsigned char hash[16];
    unsigned int len = 16;
    HMAC(EVP_md5(), bNewKey, 16, bData, 16, hash, &len);
    char* cData = new char[33];
    bytes_to_hex(hash, cData, 16);

    =>> in my code cData = "94feb52831aea0c2e85934c7850778c9"
}
```

But my result is not equal with online website that they generate HMAC MD5.

https://wtools.io/generate-hmac-hash

Data: "35413B1DD9AB9FA0F1395759BD72451C"

skey: "320E6FADB2738DA273A41E14F85027E1"

Result of them is: "bb4c6dff8a4f706b0a5206922d38a191"

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly assuming that the web site is converting the data from a hex string to bytes when it's not.

This simple example results in the same output as the web site:

```
bool test_gen_md5_hmac()
{
    std::string k = "320E6FADB2738DA273A41E14F85027E1";
    std::string d = "35413B1DD9AB9FA0F1395759BD72451C";
    unsigned char hash[16];
    unsigned int len = 16;
    HMAC(EVP_md5(), k.c_str(), k.size(), (unsigned char*)d.c_str(), d.size(), hash, &len);
    char* rv = OPENSSL_buf2hexstr(hash, 16);
    std::string rv_str(rv);
    OPENSSL_free(rv);
    return rv_str == "BB:4C:6D:FF:8A:4F:70:6B:0A:52:06:92:2D:38:A1:91";
}
```